# How to escape “ and ” with php?

Tags: php, html, encoding

I have a string which contains special quote characters (“”), among other characters which might need to be escaped in order to render correctly.

I tried using

```
htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

However it doesn't seem to work on `“` and `”`. I should think that they would get turned into `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`, but they don't.

When they are not escaped in my html document, these characters render as � in firefox.

Perhaps I have something wrong with my encoding settings, as they seem to be working fine in this post without being escaped..

Yet everything looks correct to me:

- The `Content-Type` is set to UTF-8 in `<head>`:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ```
- According to `file`, the document is saved as `UTF-8`:

  ```
  index.phtml: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
  ```
- Firefox recognizes the file as `UTF-8`.

However, straight “ and ”s don't render correctly, yet escaped versions (`&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`) do.

Comment: Curly quotes aren't special, they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: @Barmar Then why are they rendering funny? I have the charset set as UTF-8 in <head>: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: You probably don't have the correct encoding specified in the `Content-type`.

Comment: Either that or you don't have the proper encoding set when you saved your `.php` file.

Comment: @DaveChen According to my text editor, it's saved as UTF-8..

Comment: Do you have `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function converts `“` and `”` to `"`.

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(147), chr(148)); 

    $replace = array('"', '"'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

So after passing the string which contains `“` or `”` to this function it can be passed to

```
htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

as in your case `"` render correctly in the browser, the string will be shown correctly.

Another method is to replace the string with `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`

Comment: I'd like to have the quotes render as they are, ideally.. Replacing `“` with `&ldquo;` before passing the string to `htmlentities` results in the ampersands getting converted to `&amp;` so it renders literally as &ldquo;. Running it through `htmlentities` before replacing “ makes the string go away completely.

Comment: For now at least it works without `htmlentities`, so I've accepted your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$quoteLeft = ' “ ' ;

$quoteRight = ' ” ' ;

$utf = ''.$quoteLeft.'UTF-8'.$quoteRight.'';

htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, $utf);
```

Comment: I don't want to escape those quotes, I want to escape the special quote chars `“` and  `”` as stated in the question..

Answer (score -1):

To escape the quotes use backslah `\` so essentially your code will look like `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, \"UTF-8\")`

Comment: I don't want to escape those quotes, I want to escape the special quote chars `“` and  `”` as stated in the question..